# Simple jquery post variable sending

Tags: php, jquery, variables, post

I have some problem with this part of a code:

```
<script>
function komenty(photoid) {
    var xmlhttp=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            var x = xmlhttp.responseText;
            $.post('main.php', {x: "foo"});
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "comments.php?id=" + photoid, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I am trying to send this variable to my php script on the same page which is main.php
The responseText is not empty, there are few strings inside of it.
But in my php script it says that "variable x is undefined"

```
<?php
echo "<a href='#' class='my-button' onclick='komenty(".$photoid.")'>komentarze</a>";
$x = $_POST['x'];
echo $x;
?>
```

I am not sure if i clearly understand the jquery manuals

Comment: What happens if you change to `{x: "foo"}`?

Comment: @Barmar The same: "Notice: Undefined index: x in /main.php on line 627"

Comment: Undefined index is usually associated with POST variables and not having a name attribute for it, and/or an id for the form element.

Comment: @Fred-ii- He's not using a form, he's using AJAX.

Comment: Is there some way that you could be executing `main.php` without going through that `$.ajax` call? Do you ever access the script directly using the browser?

Comment: @Barmar It is really difficult to me, i am working on it like 3 days now... There is a loop posting photos from the server, and below every photo is link "comments". When you click it, it opens a popup window, and runs onclick ajax function, which sends photoID to the script downloading all comments. And here as you can see they back in ajax and are being stored in X variable and im trying to send them back to the popup window.

Comment: Maybe you need to post more code. It looks like you have two AJAX calls. The first one uses plain Javascript `XMLHttpRequest`, and then its callback function use jQuery `$.post`. What script does the first one call?

Comment: Try using $_REQUEST['x']

Comment: Is `<a href='#' class='my-button' onclick='komenty(".$photoid.")'>komentarze</a>` actually inside your PHP like that?

Comment: So `main.php` is the script that displays the page, and it's also the script you call with `AJAX`? When you display the page, there are no `POST` parameters, so you get that error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is posted by echo, i edited again sorry for that. I am trying to make it shorter as much as possible here.

Comment: @Barmar So do i have any other way to send variable from this js script to the php script on the same page?

Comment: You're sending the variable just fine. the problem isn't happening when you use AJAX, the error is happening when you display the page normally.

Comment: Probably my brain is to small to understand this haha.
I feel so hopeless, but thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use a different script for the AJAX call than displaying the main page. Or the `main.php` script needs to check whether it was called using `GET` or `POST`.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Respond to AJAX call
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    echo $x;
} else {
    // Display normal HTML
    echo "<a href='#' class='my-button' onclick='komenty(".$photoid.")'>komentarze</a>";
}
```

Comment: The else is being executed, but im not sure how to use that information :D

Comment: Glad to see a solution was found. Way to go.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well, this shows that the variable didn't go through POST right? so where did it go then XD

Comment: @asdasdasd That, I couldn't tell you. Ask Barmar ;-)

Comment: @asdasdasd When you load the page in the browser, it's a `GET` request, not a `POST`. You can access URL parameters with `$_GET['paramname']`, e.g. `main.php?foo=bar` would set `$_GET['foo']`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you sir i almost got it! I just wonder why x: "foo" is working well,  and x: x isn't. While the x variable is not empty it still do not add anything to the link

Comment: @Barmar I have found in firebug that the x variable contains "/r/n symbols at the beginning" and im using mysql without any escaping. That might be the reason i hope so :D

Comment: Yes, that would be a problem. But it wouldn't cause the `Undefined index` error that you said in your question.